# What keeps rain out of a Vertical PVC Concentric Vent?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water, heating, furnace

[image]

All pics show are the Vent Cap, which is the exhaust and the inlet air cap. What is used for a RAINCAP?

Comment: What pics are you referring to? If you intended to include some, please [edit] your question to try again - hit the "sun & mountain" button to include them, or just drag the pics into the text edit box. If you didn't intend to include pics, adding some of _your_ installation, plus an example of what you're referring to would probably help a lot. Also, what device are you venting? Plumbing? HVAC? All?

Comment: Also, please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to add pics so everyone can see what I am asking about. Anyone have ideas about that?

Comment: Look at the post editor. Click the picture icon. It's fairly intuitive. The first comment lays it out for you.

Comment: Does it _need_ a rain cap? If so, there should be _plenty_ of options to pick from at your local big-box home improvement store.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rain cap with this type of vent termination. "Why not?" you may ask?

The exhaust piping from a condensing appliance is designed to carry liquid. The appliance category is named "condensing" because these appliances extract so much heat from the exhaust gas stream that the water vapor condenses to liquid on the walls of the exhaust (vent) pipe.

It's ok if some precipitation enters the vent pipe because the pipe is liquid tight and is designed to drain these liquids back to the appliance itself. The appliance has a drain hose and sometimes a pump to remove these liquids out to the building sanitary sewer system. Clearly this arrangement can't handle the volume of water that a plumbing vent could, but it is sufficient to handle ordinary condensate and weather volumes.

The vent cap of the concentric vent, or a down-turned elbow in a two-pipe arrangement, sheds precipitation so that the combustion air inlet remains dry.